# Is there a way to use sys.exit() to exit my program without a traceback in python?

Tags: python, exit, sys, traceback

The program is ending where I want it to, with the correct SystemExit message, but a Traceback is appearing in the line before the SystemExit showing the line where it exited. Is there a way to just show the SystemExit and message without the traceback? I have 'import sys' at the beginning of the program.

The code I have for this section is:

```
if guess == 'q':
    print('q')
    sys.exit('You exited the game')
```

The unwanted output says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "filelocation\programname.py",
line 38 in <module>
    sys.exit('You exited the game')
```

The wanted output a line later says:

```
SystemExit: You exited the game
```

Answer (score 3):

The argument for `sys.exit` is **not** for you to print an exit message. It is intended to provide an [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) that should be an integer (to be honest, I'm surprised the underlying system call does not complain about the argument beeing a string).

If you want to provide a message, use `print` and call `sys.exit(0)`. Any other exit code is treated as an error, hence the stack trace.

**EDIT**: as a matter of fact, [`sys.exit` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) say that the argument for `sys.exit` can be a non-integer as a shortcut for exiting **with an error** (again, hence the stack trace).

> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. ... In particular, sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way to exit a program when an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the string out of the sys.exit:

```
import sys

guess = 'q'
if guess == 'q':
    print('q')
    print('SystemExit: You exited the game')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Okay, so I made this correction and the traceback is still coming up. Any suggestions? It's not a huge deal as the program is ending, but my perfectionism is annoying me.